# Hoje (30/06/2015) teremos um segundo a mais, quais podem ser as consequências para nossos sistemas?

Tags: datetime, sistema-operacional, time

Caso alguém não saiba, hoje `30/06/2015` teremos um segundo a mais. 
Ou seja, hoje depois das `23h59m59s` teremos `23h59m60s`!

Isso para fazer a correção do Tempo Atômico Internacional.

Sei que existem vários serviços que são sincronizados com relógios atômicos, como o que fica no [Observatório Nacional](http://www.on.br/), que podem ter problemas com esse segundo a mais.

Que tipos de problemas podemos esperar em nossos sistemas/servidores e aplicações quando ocorre um evento como esse?

Caso você não esteja sabendo de nada, veja algumas matérias falando disso:

[Radioagência Nacional - Relógios terão um segundo extra por alterações gravitacionais](http://radioagencianacional.ebc.com.br/geral/audio/2015-06/relogios-oficiais-terao-acrescimo-de-um-segundo-por-alteracoes-gravitacionais)

[Tecmundo - Dia 30 de junho terá 1 segundo a mais, mas o que isso pode causar?](http://www.tecmundo.com.br/relogio/82347-dia-30-junho-tera-1-segundo-causar.htm)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Contornando o problema

Relógios não contabilizam normalmente o segundo de número 60, portanto algumas alternativas devem ser tomadas quanto a isso. Algumas possibilidades são:

- Alguns kernels Linux implementam um pulo para trás de 1s, repetindo o 59° segundo. Para maiores informações: [Resolve Leap Second Issues in Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://access.redhat.com/articles/15145) (em Inglês);
- Servidores Windows ignoram o segundo 60, fazendo a sincronia novamente com os relógios atômicos logo depois dele passar. Isso quer dizer que eles contabilizam duas vezes o segundo 0 do dia 1° de julho. Para maiores informações: [How the Windows Time service treats a leap second](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/909614) (em Inglês);
- Algumas organizações incluindo a Amazon Web Services, planejam dividir e espalhar o segundo extra por várias horas, ao fazer cada segundo um pouquinho mais longo (o termo em Inglês é "leap smear");
- Se o relógio não se conecta a um sistema de sincronização, ele simplesmente não implementa nenhum tipo de ajuste para isso.

Fonte: [Look Before You Leap – The Coming Leap Second and AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/aws/look-before-you-leap-the-coming-leap-second-and-aws/?tag=viglink121320-20)

## Possíveis complicações

Muitos dispositivos tecnológicos sincronizam seus relógios com um relógio atômico. Entretanto, muitos deles não foram programados para considerar a possibilidade do segundo extra acontecer, portanto, quando o sistema o identifica ele apresenta um resultado não previsto, o que pode resultar em *crashes* de servidores e consequentemente em queda de seus serviços.

Em 2012, Mozilla, Reddit, Foursquare, Yelp, LinkedIn e StumbleUpon, apresentaram *crashes* de sistema quando o segundo extra foi adicionado. Já o Google, que usou a tática do "leap smear", escapou ileso dessa situação.

Esse ano é esperado que alguns servidores apresentem novamente esse problema.

Fonte: [Daily News - 'Leap second' coming up June 30 may cause computer system problems](http://www.nydailynews.com/news/world/leap-june-30-computer-system-problems-article-1.2069115)

## Atualização: Quais foram os danos do segundo extra de 2015?

Apesar da AWS dizer que não foi culpa do segundo extra, seus serviços ficaram fora do ar por pouco mais de 40 minutos, mas não ás `00:00 UTC` e sim das `00:25` às `01:07 UTC`, deixando fora do ar serviços como Slack, Netflix, Pinterest e milhares de outros websites e serviços.

A notícia:

> Between 5:25 PM and 6:07 PM PDT we experienced an Internet connectivity issue with a provider outside of our network which affected traffic from some end-user networks. The issue has been resolved and the service is operating normally.
>
> The root cause of this issue was an external Internet service provider incorrectly accepting a set of routes for some AWS addresses from a third-party who inadvertently advertised these routes. Providers should normally reject these routes by policy, but in this case the routes were accepted and propagated to other ISPs affecting some end-user’s ability to access AWS resources. Once we identified the provider and third-party network, we took action to route traffic around this incorrect routing configuration. We have worked with this external Internet service provider to ensure that this does not reoccur.

Fonte: [AWS Service Health Dashboard](http://status.aws.amazon.com/)

Segundo eles, a culpa foi de servidores externos que aceitaram incorretamente um conjunto de rotas para alguns endereços AWS que foram anunciados inadvertidamente por terceiros... Não ficou claro para você? Para mim também não. O fato é que muita gente desconfia que o problema foi sim do segundo extra, apesar da AWS afirmar que não.

Fonte: [Mashable - Slack, Netflix, Pinterest crash and you can't blame the leap second](http://mashable.com/2015/06/30/aws-disruption/)

Comment: Obrigado pela atualização com notícias de hoje. Fiz a pergunta justamente por acreditar que nos depararíamos com comportamentos "estranhos" nos dias seguintes.

Comment: De nada. Dei uma olhada pelas notícias mas ainda não vi nada de mais grave, acho que estão aprendendo a lidar com essa situação :)

Answer (score 7):

Esta pergunta é relacionada à um dos temas de uma das [respostas mais famosas do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/1064325), pelo renomado [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), no SOen.

Haverá uma descontinuidade temporal.

Uma descontinuidade pode acontecer de duas formas:

- Avanço no relógio
- Atraso no relógio

Ambas podem gerar problemas se seu código não for tratado corretamente.

Neste caso, haverá um *atraso no relógio*, no horário `23:59:59` na ordem de 1 segundo.

---

Apesar de ser tratado se forma diferente, vale a pena notar que no horário de verão também ocorre exatamente esse mesmo problema de descontinuidade, e por ainda mais tempo do que 1 segundo: 1 hora!

Como já trabalhei em sistemas de cobrança, posso afirmar que os seguintes casos acontecem:

- Avanço no relógio (`00:00:00` pula para `01:00:00`)

  - Uma ligação é iniciada em `23:59:00`, e finalizada em `01:00:00`: a ligação durou apenas `00:01:00`.
- Atraso no relógio (`00:00:00` volta para `23:00:00`)

  - Uma ligação é iniciada em `23:30:00`, e finalizada em `23:31:00`: a ligação pode ter durado tanto `00:01:00`quanto também `01:01:00`.

Uma solução pode ser utilizar (por debaixo dos panos) uma forma de horário neutra (que desconsidere essas descontinuidades), outra seria tratá-las.

Comment: Grande Jon Skeet, apesar de ser especializado em C#, sua resposta mais votada é sobre Java.

Answer (score 4):

Oque vai ocorrer é que no relógio ele vai prender um segundo durante a virada da noite.

**Nota:** A informação abaixo varia de S.O. e de Linguagem de Programação.

**Dica:** Adiante o relógio de seu computador, e teste a aplicação.

> Exemplo que ocorrerá ás **23h 59m e 59s**: 50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,**59**,**59**,00

Esse segundo vai ser apresentado duas vezes os impactos para sistemas financeiros e que usam tempo como base financeira vai ser o processamento do mesmo segundo "**23:59:59**" duas vezes.

**Mas cada aplicação tem sua função, e o desenvolvedor que deve saber qual será o comportamento que seu código vai apresentar nessa situação.**

Parabéns pela pergunta!

Answer (score 1):

Esse segundo a mais pode causar diversos problemas nos sistemas que desenvolvemos e usamos, desde uma simples `exception` até tirar o sistema completamente do ar.

Isso ocorre pois grande parte dos sistemas não está preparado para lidar com esse segundo a mais, para esses sistemas o segundo 60 não existe.

> Em 2012, por exemplo, a última vez em que um segundo extra precisou ser incluso nos relógios atômicos, Mozilla, Reddit, Foursquare, Yelp, LinkedIn, StumbleUpon, o sistema operacional Linux, programas desenvolvidos em Java, por exemplo; apresentaram falhas e muitos até saíram do ar.

A razão para este problema deve-se a problemas no código dos sistemas operativos ou das aplicações de suporte que ao verem surgir este segundo adicional acabam por congelar devido a bugs ou falha de programação.

Até o momento somente a google se manifestou sobre o caso, e alegou que diversas técnicas estão sendo desenvolvidas para lidar com o problema e não afetar os usuários.

Fontes: [Fatos Desconhecidos](http://www.fatosdesconhecidos.com.br/2015-tera-1-segundo-mais-e-isso-pode-fazer-internet-cair/), [pplware](http://pplware.sapo.pt/internet/2015-vai-ter-mais-1-segundo-e-isso-sera-perigoso-para-a-internet/)

Comment: O segundo 60 não vai existir hoje @RodrigoBorth. Os relógios vão repetir o segundo 59.

Comment: Rodrigo, como a pergunta foi feita em cima dos sistemas. Então falei oque será feito pela BIOS (Basic Input Output System) quando chegar no segundo 59. As **maquinas** que não são relógios atômicos não executaram o segundo 60.

Comment: Não tirei de fonte alguma, adiante o relógio do seu computador, crie um laço de repetição a cada segundo e mande exibir no console e você verá

Comment: Mas como você mesmo informou em sua resposta, isso pode variar de sistema e de linguagens, meu teste com o PHP resultou nisso. Estou operando sobre o apache no windows, PHP 5.6.10.

Comment: Sim como disse, você tem razão e coloquei uma nota em minha resposta. Obrigado a atenção

Answer (score 0):

Conforme o próprio link que você passou, existe a seguinte informação:

> A correção do "Segundo intercalado" é determinada pelo Serviço Internacional de Sistemas de Referência e Rotação da Terra. O último acerto aconteceu no dia 31 de dezembro de 2012.
>
> Esses ajustes de um segundo são feitos desde 1972 e a partir de julho deste ano, a diferença entre o Tempo Atômico Internacional e o Tempo Universal Coordenado (UTC) vai ser de 36 segundos.

Provavelmente os servidores irão adiantar os seus horários e mesmo que houve-se o horário `23:59:60` as tecnologias se previnem disto, no caso o `23:59:60` seria convertido provavelmente para `00:00:00`, note também sistemas na informática operam no UTC/GMT.

Um exemplo com o motor javascript para testar:

```js
var test = document.getElementById("test");

document.getElementById("run").onclick = function() {
    //new Date(anom, mês, dia, horas, minutos, segundos, milisegundos)
    var date = new Date(2015, 05, 30, 23, 59, 60, 0);
    test.innerHTML = date;
};
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<button id="run">Testar</button>
```

Comment: Se você gostaria de se referir ao dia do problema (30/06/2015), lembre-se que o [Objeto Date do javascript o mês (_mouth_) é base zero, indo de 0 a 11, onde 0 é Janeiro e 11 é Dezembro](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Então para representar o dia do problema da pergunta em seu exemplo javascript, você deveria utilizar o seguintes parâmetros para o construtor do objeto Date: `var date = new Date(2015, 05, 30, 23, 59, 60, 0);`

Comment: @Fernando Obrigado já corrigido, acredito ser um erro comum de falta de atenção e você pode editar quando for assim

Comment: Só não editei, pois não sabia qual era sua real intenção. Então preferi comentar =D